# Is it possible to connect Maptitude 5 with Oracle Spatial?

Tags: oracle-spatial, maptitude

I have a version of Maptitude 5, and I need to connect it to Oracle Spatial. 
I have the client installed on the machine, including the connection to the database using Qgis and gvSIG and this works normally. 
Using Maptitude:

1. Open File Menu
2. Files of type: Oracle Spatial Layer
3. In the window that I've opened, entered User, Password and Service

This then gave an error that the connection was not performed with these parameters, but these are the parameters used in Qgis and gvSIG.

I know this is an old version of Maptitude, but I wonder if anyone uses or has used this version connected to Oracle Spatial.

Comment: Since version 4.5 Oracle Spatial is supported http://www.caliper.com/PDFs/Maptitude_6_New_Features.pdf

Comment: Ok, could you tell me if the choice I made to open Oracle Spatial Layer is the right to access the layers of the database because it did not work. Recalling that the connection is successful with other GIS

Comment: sounds like your oracle home (full client) is not correct for Maptitude - your better of contacting Caliper support http://www.caliper.com/ovucntct.htm